# How can I easily harvest Glowstone in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the best way to retreive Glowstone in the nether? Usually it spawns above the lava and I'm having a hard time making bridges out of the netherrack.

Comment: An amusing way is to deflect Ghast shots into it :D

Comment: I play mostly in peaceful mode so that wont help me.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, it still wouldn't help for harvesting glowstone over lava, but it is fun!

Comment: Is your issue with bridges in general?  Or bridges with netherrack?

Comment: You know that crouching (hold shift) makes you able to walk out to the very edge of a block without falling off, right? It makes it easy to walk backwards and build a bridge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Glowstone spawns in clusters on the ceiling of the nether usually. My preferred method for gathering it is to walk underneath a cluster, piller up with dirt or something else easily diggable, then build a platform underneath, so that as you break it no glowstone escapes.

When you're done, simply dig back down your pillar. On peaceful mode with no ghasts, this should be relatively straightforward :)

Comment: He needed help with it being over lava

Comment: @AliceRees It's often over lava because much of the nether is, well, lava. Just find some that isn't is the best advice I can give...

Comment: This still works just fine if it's over lava.  If you haven't mastered making horizontal bridges and vertical pillars in Minecraft, you should practice - it's useful.

Answer (score 4):

I always take some stacks of cobblestone with me. The main reason is it act as barriers against Ghasts' fireballs.

You can also build bridges using the backward sneak method (can't fall when sneaking). Build yourself a platform and build up.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the solei method, and use nettherack from mining a bit and pillarig up

Comment: Teh what method? Please provide links and more information. And (not saying it applies to this case) check if the other answers already contain your answer. You could try suggesting an edit if you have a specific improvement for an answer.